# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision

Tags: firebase, flutter

When I added flutter_camera_ml_vision to an existing project, I got the following error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.                 
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:.            
     Required by:                                                       
         project :app > project :firebase_ml_vision
```

I didn't know what caused it, so I copied the code (from the official website).
After that, I tried to link firebase and added only flutter_camera_ml_vision, but I got the same error as above.

The main.dart is the same as the URL above, and the other files that I changed are as follows.
The version of flutter_camera_ml_vision is 3.0.1.
As a supplement, the ./gradlew command succeeds.

//android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.association_firebase">
   <application
        android:label="association_firebase"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <!-- add -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

//android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// add
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.association_firebase"
        minSdkVersion 21   // changed to 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
    // add
    dependencies {
        api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:19.0.0'
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //add
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    //add
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

//android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        //add
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got similar when using `firebase_ml_vision: ^0.12.0+2`,

then I downgrade to `firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.10` and added following in `app/build.gradle`:

> implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'

then app can be compiled.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by moving to the recommended, non-deprecated package at https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit.

The API is fairly similar, so not many code changes should be needed. See the [migration guide](https://pub.dev/packages/google_ml_kit#migrating-from-ml-kit-for-firebase) for more info.